# Any documentaion available for behaviour of unsigned char pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, char, unsigned

What is an unsigned char pointer and how is it different from a char pointer in C?

Not much information on unsigned char pointer in C , and How to print the data pointed by an unsigned char pointer?

Any explanation on this will be helpful.

Comment: The problem is in the line of code you didn't show. Otherwise the message is pretty clear: %d expcects an int and you provide an unsigned int*. This is _undefined behaviour_ (google that)

Comment: Just added a sample c code snippet :
 unsigned char* temp;
    temp= 133+2;
    
    printf("%d",temp);

Comment: You probably meant to do `printf("%u",(unsigned int)*temp);`

Comment: I think you should read the chapter dealing with pointers in your C text book. `char* temp; temp= 133+2;` is pretty pointless, maybe you meant `char temp; temp= 133+2;`?

Comment: @Lundin I don't think so, look at his code snippet in the second comment

Comment: @VibhutiSawant remove the star `*`

Comment: @P__J__ probably, but without more information from the OP it's hard to tell.

Comment: @VibhutiSawant what is you code supposed to do? What output do you expect. Probably just `unsigned char* temp;` -> `unsigned char temp;`, but we need more information

Comment: @Jabberwocky the main aim to ask the question was to know the functionality of unsigned char pointer, and how to get the data its pointing to.

I am more interested in knowing the memory representation and the byte of memory temp is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have something like

```
unsigned char *p = something;
```

then

```
printf( “p = %p\n”, (void *)p );
```

prints the value of the pointer itself, while

```
printf( “*p = %hhu\n”, *p );
```

prints the value of what `p` points to as a decimal integer (unsigned).

Comment: Not quite sure if this is the correct answer. I suspect the OP doesn't even know what a pointer is, but without more information it's hard to tell

Answer (score 0):

the documentation is here: https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

```
unsigned char x = 0x4d;
unsigned char *y = &x;

printf("pointer: %p, %hhu\n", (void *)y, *y);
```

endianess do not matter as `sizeof(unsgined char)` id always 1.

If you want to pun types via pointers - it is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Not quite sure if this is the correct answer, apparently the OP provided the a pointer instead of  value, but without seeing his code it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

How to print the data pointed to by an `unsigned char* p`?

That depends entirely on the datas format. And what you want actually have and what you need.

Is it just a binary blob of known length?
You probably want a hexdump then. Search for it, while it is common, it is not builtin, and there are many options.

Is it really a null terminated string?
Print it using `%s` after casting to `char*`.

Is it just a single `unsigned char`?
Print it using `%hhu` after dereferencing.

There is really insufficient information to judge what is needed.